# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name' In TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Hi I am learning typescript.

I have in my code.

```
var name:string="Hello world";
console.log(name);
```

while compile time I am getting this error.

```
error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name'.
index.ts(4,5): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name'.
```

Can someone describe me why I am getting this error?

Comment: In which context are you trying to execute this code ?

Comment: The error seems to suggest that you've already got a variable called `name` in scope.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `name` property is defined on the `window` object:

```
interface Window extends EventTarget, WindowTimers, WindowSessionStorage, WindowLocalStorage, WindowConsole, GlobalEventHandlers, IDBEnvironment, WindowBase64, GlobalFetch {
    ...
    name: string;
    ...
}
```

(https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L17226)

You'll need to come up with a new name for your variable:

```
var myname = "Hello world";
console.log(myname);
```

Answer (score 13):

You can add `export{}` at the beginning of your file.

Comment: Could you explain a bit why to do so.

Comment: @rahul, the `export {}` makes it a module and so it has its own module scope and can thus use `name` without a class. See https://medium.com/@muravitskiy.mail/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-varname-how-to-fix-b1c3d9cc8206

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `name` has already been declared somewhere in the same block of code. And it is not allowed.

This is exactly the meaning of the error message.

The cause being that, you tried to declare this particular variable on global scope, and here `name` is already defined for some technical reason, for more details see : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9850

(Thanks [@betadeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8928802/betadeveloper) )

Comment: No. It is a global in the browser - _window.name_ and in typescript they decided to declare it as a _const_, see this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9850

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I edited my answer adding the cause on this specific case.

Comment: @Pac0 Thanx Brother :-)