# cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'jQuery'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

**The question**

How do I stop *VS Code* from showing `declare var jQuery:any;` as an error?

**More info**

[image: vs code cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'jQuery']

**What i've done**

After a quick search I found a suggestion [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533282/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-name-in-typescript?rq=1), which suggests that the `jQuery` variable has already been defined elsewhere in the same code block. So I delete this reference. *VS Code* stops complaining but the console show the below error and my app will not compile.

> ERROR in src/app/app.config.ts(34,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jQuery'.
>   src/app/pages/pages.component.ts(31,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jQuery'.

So I re-add the line i just removed and my application complies but I get the below error in the browser (in dev tools console)

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __webpack_require__.e is not a function
TypeError: __webpack_require__.e is not a function
    at webpackAsyncContext (eval at ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive (main.bundle.js:13), <anonymous>:11:29)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:6554)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:6538)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:4543)
    at RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:4523)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.js:2015)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:128)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:118)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at ScalarObservable._subscribe (ScalarObservable.js:51)
    at webpackAsyncContext (eval at ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive (main.bundle.js:13), <anonymous>:11:29)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:6554)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:6538)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:4543)
    at RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:4523)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.js:2015)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:128)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:118)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at ScalarObservable._subscribe (ScalarObservable.js:51)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
    at eval (zone.js:858)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4736)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at <anonymous>
```

So I terminate the app and restart it. Now the app runs with no errors but *VS Code* shows that same problem again.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `import $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue in an Angular5 project. There is no webpack config in Angular-CLI projects so we cannot modify that to provide plugin solution as per @IWallent's answer. The problem is that by installing @types/jquery (as I suspect you have) 'jQuery' is already declared, so declaring it again throws the VSCode warning. What I don't understand is why removing it (as you did - deleting the declare reference) breaks the app - why can't the browser/code see the one declared via @types/jquery?

Answer (score 1):

May be below steps will solve your problem.
Let me know your comments.

---

1.) install jquery types and jquery from npm

```
npm install jquery
npm install @types/jquery
```

---

2.) add jquery to .angular-cli.json

```
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      ],
```

---

3.) declare in your pages.component.ts file.

```
declare let $: any;
declare let jQuery: any;
```

Comment: Question doesn't mention the Angular CLI. Regardless, this is crap.

Comment: @AluanHaddad i asked `How do I stop VS Code from showing declare var jQuery:any; as an error?` if the cli is a way to stop that, I don't see the problem in mentioning in the answer. Also maybe you could provide some constructive criticism? @MayurPatel thanks for your suggestion

Comment: The CLI isn't stopping the error. Constructive feedback: `package-manager install @types/jquery` instead

Comment: The question does not mention the Angular CLI but I suspect quite strongly that it should - examining all the code snippets and errors from the OP makes me 99% certain that he has an Angular 5 or 6 project built with CLI. In which case there is no webpack config file. He already has installed @types/jquery and is now redeclaring jquery as a global in his typing.d.ts file (because without it the app cannot compile, as the OP states). So what he needs is a way for the app to 'see' the global jQuery declared by installing @types/jquery (and therefore not needing to redeclare it in typings.d.ts.)

Comment: @Mayur Patel I already have steps (1) and (2) in my project and have the same problem as the OP. Step (3) does not fix it - same compile error as OP gets (Cannot find name 'jQuery').

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have two problems.

The first being declaring jQuery (you are already using **@types/jquery**, right?). VS Code is probably right about it already being declared. So remove that.

The second problem is that some of your components cannot find jQuery when running webpack, right?

Here I would suggest you use the ProvidePlugin in your **webpack** config:

```
//=============================================
// Provide PLUGIN - making things available
//=============================================
const provideVars = new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
}); 

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    provideVars
  ],
  ...

};
```

Comment: I suspect the op has the problem that he has no webpack config file. I have the exact same issue in an Angular5 project, which was built using angular-cli so there is no webpack config.