# Create an object from an Interface using variables (in Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to typescript, and I'm trying to create a new object for an Interface that I defined. I know that I can do something like this:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}


const me: Person = {
  name: "John"
  age: 28,
};
```

However, what if I'd like to declare the variables first, and then build the object based on the variables I declared like this:

```
  interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

let name: string = "albert"
let age: number = 28

const me: Person = {
  name: name
  age: age,
};
```

This gives me the following error "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'." Any idea of what's going on here?

Comment: That looks fine. Can you reproduce this issue online?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L17878

Comment: I copied your codes and there is no error are you sure you get this error from these codes

Comment: `name` is declared in the DOM typings so not available for use as a variable in this case.

Comment: duplicate: [Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name' In TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533282/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-name-in-typescript)